# c# How to call variables from another class

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am using dapper with sqlite

I have two classes **(Data, Inputs)**

I have multi classes in **(Data)** and multi variables in **(Inputs)**

classes(tables in database) in **Data** (D1, D2, D3) and all it have the same columns (firstname, lastname)

variables in **Inputs** (firstname, lastname)

i want to make **(D1, D2, D3)** can set and get **(firstname, lastname)** from Inputs to insert the values into **(D1, D2, D3)**

my try but it does not work

```
public class Inputs
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}

public class Data : Inputs
{
    public class D1 { }
    public class D2 { }
    public class D3 { }
}
```

i want to make this

```
Data.D1> d1 = Data.D1;
d1.firstname = "the name";
d1.lastname = "another name";
```

Comment: do you mean passing the `Inputs` object to the constructor of `Data' class? Can you explain adequately? it's not clear from your question.

Comment: This sounds like a homework assignment for a class project, Stack Overflow is not here to do your homework for you. If you have a specific question to ask, please ask it and provide all of the necessary details, but please do not expect people to do your homework for you especially when you have not provided anywhere near enough information to understand the problem at hand.

Comment: not my homework i can not solve the problem

Comment: @viveknuna i want to make this (List<Data.First> LLL = new List<Data.First>(); LLL.firstname = "name";

Comment: @DoneNothing so whats the issue? and its still not clear by the question that what exactly are you trying to do

Comment: when try to do it i can not call firstname and lastname

Comment: @DoneNothing Can you take a pause and read your question again? Do you think others will understand your problem, If you find then please edit your question? Otherwise it will be closed

Comment: i`m using Dapper with sqlite and i want to set value for columns all the class in Data have the same columns

Comment: Edited Please help if the question has become understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this.

```
public class Inputs
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public class D1 : Inputs { }
    public class D2 { }
    public class D3 { }
}

Data.D1 d1 = new Data.D1();
d1.firstname = "first";
```

Comment: yes it`s correct

Comment: can i ask you ?

Comment: yes @DoneNothing

Comment: thanks Mr vivek! I want to make a function like this for my situation private void gg(Data d, Class s){ d.s = new d.s(); } any way to do it ?

Comment: @DoneNothing class is not a defined keyword in C#. and in which class do you want to declare this method?

Comment: i have 100 class in Data form D1 to D100 is there a way to skip writing the same code for all 100 classes

Comment: Give me 20 mins, I’m away from desk @DoneNothing

Comment: But why do you need 100 classes? Do you want to define a same method in all the classes? Or each class will have different logic to be implemented? Or the same logic?

Comment: all the same logic

Comment: @DoneNothing that should be a different question. Can you add a new question and share the link with me

Comment: I can only post once every 90 minutes.

Comment: can i edit this question then put another under it ?

Comment: @DoneNothing new question

Comment: ok i will put the link in an comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74487390/c-sharp-how-to-define-a-same-method-in-all-the-classes