# How to define a same method in all the classes

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

```
public class Inputs
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public class D1 : Inputs { }
    public class D2 : Inputs { }
    public class D3 : Inputs { }
}

Data.D1 d1 = new Data.D1();
d1.firstname = "first";

Data.D2 d2 = new Data.D2();
d2.firstname = "first";

Data.D3 d3 = new Data.D3();
d3.firstname = "first";
```

I have 100 classes in Data form D1 to D100 is there a way to skip writing the same code for all 100 classes

Comment: You can create a method in `Inputs`. But why do you have D1, D2, D3, etc? What is the point of it?

Comment: it`s countries each one have same columns but diffrent data

Comment: So why not just have a `Country` class?

Comment: can you type a code as answer ?

Comment: Then do map aka dictionary not single class for each country

Comment: are the classes doing exactly the same thing ? do they have the exactly methods? if your answer is yes, you do not need more classes, you need just instances, if your class has the same base and is related use an abstract class

Comment: yes exactly the same thing

Comment: Then don't create multiple classes because that's silly.

Comment: any one can answer by example please

Comment: An example of what? You know hoe to create instances of your classes because you're doing it already. `Data.D1 d1 = new Data.D1(); d1.firstname = "first";` - there's nothing to stop you creating another instance of `D1` with a different variable name (e.g. not `d1` but maybe `bob`).

Comment: i have a table for each class on my database instance will do what i need ?

Comment: there D1, D2, D3 to D100 as a tables in database

Comment: 1. I don't know what database you're using. 2. I don't know how you're querying that database, if you're using an ORM, etc.

Comment: i am using Sqlite3

Comment: Presumably you are doing something where you pass a type argument to a generic method (e.g. `GetRecords<D1>(someQuery)`) or something? Code would really help here. I suggest you edit your question to show that.

Comment: I see you accepted Vivek's answer. I assume that means you don't want to find out the correct way of writing your code.

Comment: Look, perhaps you have something like `IEnumerable<Data.D1> d1 = db.Query<Data.D1>("select * from D1");` (I see one SQLite library does it like this). There is nothing to stop you from writing `IEnumerable<Country> d1 = db.Query<Country>("select * from D1"); IEnumerable<Country> d2 = db.Query<Country>("select * from D2");`, reusing the same class. Your data is stored in the instance, not the class.

Comment: I agree with all the above comments by ProgrammingLIam, Selvin and DonMiguelSanchez. @DoneNothing, they are helping you to learn here you should start reading about OOP first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should explore [Abstract class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract), Base class or [Virtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual) methods in C#.

There are many ways to solve this issue. But again it depends on the requirement.

you can use the Abstract class if you want the implementation in one class and derived classes should use the same implementation.

```
public abstract class Inputs
{
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod");
    }
}
```

One way is to just inherit from a Base class and just implement the method in the base class.

Another way is to use virtual with the method and override in the child class if you want to override the base class method implementation.

```
public virtual void SomeMethod()
{
    Console.WriteLine("SomeMethod");
}
```

I would suggest you read  [Object Oriented Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/oop) concepts like [Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/tutorials/inheritance), Abstraction, and [Polymorphism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/object-oriented/polymorphism).

**Note**: But you have a really bad design of your application, It's not good practise to have 100 classes for the exact same functionality. Although my above answer can help you. But you have to revisit and start redesigning your application. This is not going to help in future.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned „countries“ I believe you are looking for a way to initialize the data, since the data of the countries may be static and won’t change.

Consider this:

```
public class Inputs
{
    public string firstname { get; }
    public string lastname { get; }
}

public class Data
{
    public class D1 : Inputs
    { 
        public D1()
        {
            firstName = "first";
        }
    }
}
```